# PDFView.page.getViewport() not defined?

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf.js

So I'm using the normal viewer.html and the following function included in a separate .js:

```
function selectedPosition()
{
    var visible = PDFView.getVisiblePages();
    var firstPage = visible.first;
    var pageNumber = firstPage.id;
    var currentPage = PDFView.pages[pageNumber - 1];

    var selecion = window.getSelection();
    var range = selecion.getRangeAt(0);
    var rect = range.getBoundingClientRect();

    var div = $('#viewer');
    var viewport = currentPage.getViewport(div.width / currentPage.getViewport(1.0).width); // Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

    var point1 = viewport.convertToPdfPoint(rect.left - div.offset().left, rect.top - div.offset().top);
    var point2 = viewport.convertToPdfPoint(rect.right - div.offset().left, rect.bottom - div.offset().top);

    console.log(point1);
    console.log(point2);
}
```

What the code should do, is calculate the rectangle points with respect to the pdf so that they are independent on scrolling and zoom.
The code is mostly copied from the viewer.js, so why is getViewport not defined?

Trying

```
console.log(currentPage.getViewport(1.0));
```

yields the same error. What am I missing?

Comment: The API for the viewer is not defined: PDFView is deprecated use PDFViewerApplication instead. Also PDFView.pages contained PageView objects and not Page objects, so getViewport is not available there.

Comment: What should I use instead of `PDFView.getVisiblePages();` and `getPage` then? The pagerendered event triggers too early when the textlayer (which I need) isn't finished yet.

Comment: PDFViewerApplication.pdfViewer._getVisiblePages however it's likely a private method and might be removed in the future. In new versions text layer will generate 'textlayerrendered' event.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the "viewport" property of the PageView object that is returned by the call to PDFView.pages[pageNumber - 1]. For example:

```
function selectedPosition()
{
    var visible = PDFView.getVisiblePages();
    var firstPage = visible.first;
    var pageNumber = firstPage.id;
    var currentPage = PDFView.pages[pageNumber - 1];

    ...

    //var viewport = currentPage.getViewport(div.width / currentPage.getViewport(1.0).width);
    var viewport = currentPage.viewport; // Should return a reference to the viewport for the page

    ...
}
```